# 3D wireframe algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

We need to convert wireframe representations of 3D objects into a representation consisting of 6 orthogonal views each containing nested (non intersecting) closed contours, each having a Z (depth/height) value. We are only concerned with 3D shapes compatible with the target representation. Can someone at least point us to any related existing algorithms?

Comment: How is the input given? What is known about the wireframe-models (i.e., what kind of mesh is it?)  What is know about the topology of the objects?

Comment: The input is a .step file but we have code to parse that to wireframe. I don't know what kind of mesh .step uses but simple shapes have minimal wires. For example a hole might be 3 circles and 2 straights. About the topology we can assume it is restricted to shapes that can be represented by the above described target representation (the Z value extrudes the contour).